# jquery tmpl inside each

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

I have a set of templates iterating via {{each}} statement.
Code is like

```
    <script id="inTmpl" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
         ${sub.title}
    </script>
    <script id="outTmpl" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
         <div>
         {{each(i, sub) parent}}
              ${sub.title}
              {{tmpl "#inTmpl"}}
         {{/each}}
         </div>
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
          $(function() {
               $("#outTmpl").tmpl({
                    "parent": [
                        {"title": "a"},
                        {"title": "b"}
                    ]
               }).appendTo("body");
          });
    </script>
```

Then I get error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: sub is not defined". Why?!

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the new template the sub object I believe.

So the line that renders the second template should look like

```
    {{tmpl(sub) "#inTmpl"}}
```

Here's where I got the info. I haven't tried it myself yet.

http://skilldrick.co.uk/tmpl/#slide14

Answer (score 1):

You can find archived documentation here:
http://web.archive.org/web/20120921050105/http://api.jquery.com/template-tag-tmpl/

Here is a working version:

```
<script id="inTmpl" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
  ${title}
</script>

<script id="outTmpl" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
  <div>
    {{each(i, sub) parent}}
      ${sub.title}
      {{tmpl(sub) "#inTmpl"}}
    {{/each}}
  </div>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $("#outTmpl").tmpl({
    "parent": [
      {"title": "a"},
      {"title": "b"}
    ]
  }).appendTo("body");
});
</script>
```